# Mechanical work done when standing up

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, estimation

Suppose you squat. As you stand up, about how much mechanical work do your muscles do?

Your weight is $500 N$. Your center of mass moves at a constant speed from a height of $H_{CM}=0.2 m$ to $H_{CM}^′=1.2 m$ in $1s$. The answer is between $500J$ to $525J$.

$W_{mech}=ΔK+ΔU$ so solving for $\Delta U=500N\cdot(1.2m-0.2m)=500J$ is trivial. I am confused about solving for kinetic energy. At first you are stationary so $v_0=0$ so $\Delta K=0.5\frac{w}{g}v^2$. Then the explanation says:

"It is somewhat unclear what happens to your kinetic energy as you reach your full height and come to rest. Either your muscles can relax as you near your full height, using gravity to slow your motion, in which case there is a transformation of kinetic into potential energy. Alternatively, friction forces can oppose your upward motion, dissipating your kinetic energy as heat, and none of your kinetic energy is converted to potential energy.".

I think in former scenario the kinetic energy turns into potential energy at maximum height where it is stationary too so $\Delta K=0J$ thus mechanical energy is $500N$. But I don't understand why in latter scenario the $\Delta K=25J$. Mechanical energy just accounts for change in kinetic and change in potential energy so I think change in K is still $0J$ since velocity at initial and final is $0\frac{m}{s}$. Am I wrong? If I am wrong why am I wrong?

Comment: *"Mechanical energy just accounts for change in kinetic and change in potential energy"*. The problem lies here. When a rolling ball comes to a stop, where does the kinetic energy go? At the final state, there's no kinetic energy and no potential energy. It goes into thermal energy. You need another term in your equation to account for that.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Show me how it is done. I know it goes to thermal equation but why 525J? That's where I am confused how do I represent mechanical energy formula with thermal energy.

Comment: Just add a term for thermal energy. The work done on the system increases the sum of the kinetic, potential, and thermal energy. Now you can accommodate friction losses.

Comment: @Chemomechanics So you mean $E_{mech}=\Delta K+\Delta K+Thermal$? But definition for Mechanical Energy is Change in Kinetic plus potential energy. I am confused.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood mechanical work and energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the forces of nature, the force generated by muscle requires energy input. This is because muscle contraction is caused by myosin heads repeatedly binding to actin and advancing along the actin molecule. Biological processes like these are nowhere near 100% efficient: the myosin heads occasionally slip backward.

[image]

The transfer of energy from ATP to the myosin head during the power stroke is inefficient. This energy is dissipated mostly as heat, which is why animals sweat during physical activity.

Comment: Wait, what? Muscle cells don't actually shrink inwards as much as two interleaved sets of fingers crawl along each other? Are those images implying muscles kind of work like...a conveyor belt of of fingers? Or two caterpillars crawling along each other in opposite directions?